# Get week number of given date by passing start and end date in java

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to get week number of given date that lies between start and end date.
Below is the code i have used to get but it works only for 4 weeks.

I need it to make it to work for any number of weeks.

```
public static int getWeekNO( Timestamp startTime,Timestamp endTime , Timestamp dateTime) throws RuntimeException {

        String formatted = null;
        Timestamp currentTimestamp;
        int weekNumber = 0;

        logger.debug("startTime"+startTime);
        logger.debug("endTime"+endTime);
        logger.debug("dateTime"+dateTime);
        try {
            String formatDateFirst =  "";
            String formatDateSecond = "";
            String formatDateThird = "";
            String formatDateFourth = "";
            String givenDateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(dateTime);
            String startDateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(startTime);
            String endDateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(endTime);
            logger.debug("givenDateString"+givenDateString);
            logger.debug("startDateString"+startDateString);
            logger.debug("endDateString"+endDateString);


            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date givenDate = sdf.parse(givenDateString);
            Date startDate = sdf.parse(startDateString);
            Date endDate = sdf.parse(endDateString);

            logger.debug("givenDate"+givenDate);
            logger.debug("startDate"+startDate);
            logger.debug("endDate"+endDate);

            c.setTime(sdf.parse(startDateString));

            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 6); // number of days to add
            formatDateFirst = sdf.format(c.getTime());
            Date firstWeekDate = (Date) sdf.parse(formatDateFirst);
            logger.debug("endDate"+firstWeekDate);

            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7); // number of days to add
            formatDateSecond = sdf.format(c.getTime());
            Date secondWeekDate = (Date) sdf.parse(formatDateSecond);
            logger.debug("endDate"+secondWeekDate);

            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7); // number of days to add
            formatDateThird = sdf.format(c.getTime());
            Date thirdWeekDate = (Date) sdf.parse(formatDateThird);
            logger.debug("endDate"+thirdWeekDate);

            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7); // number of days to add
            formatDateFourth = sdf.format(c.getTime());
            Date fourthWeekDate = (Date) sdf.parse(formatDateFourth);
            logger.debug("endDate"+fourthWeekDate);


            if (givenDate.compareTo(firstWeekDate) <= 0) {
                weekNumber = 1;
            } else if (givenDate.compareTo(secondWeekDate) <= 0
                    && givenDate.compareTo(firstWeekDate) > 0) {
                weekNumber = 2;
                } else if (givenDate.compareTo(thirdWeekDate) <= 0
                    && givenDate.compareTo(secondWeekDate) > 0) {
                    weekNumber = 3;
            }else if (givenDate.compareTo(fourthWeekDate) <= 0
                    && givenDate.compareTo(thirdWeekDate) > 0) {
                    weekNumber = 4;
            }else{
                logger.debug("Not a Valid Date");
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
        return weekNumber;
    }
```

Example:

```
  start Timestamp: 09/04/2016 00:00:00,End Timestamp: 28/06/2016 00:00:00. Given Timestamp : 15/05/2016 00:00:00

so here:week 1:09/04/2016 - 15/04/2016
        week 2:16/04/2016 - 22/04/2016
        week 3:23/04/2016 - 29/04/2016
        week 4:30/04/2016 - 06/05/2016
        week 5:07/05/2016 - 13/05/2016
        week 6:14/05/2016 - 20/05/2016 -- my given timestamp falls here
        week 7:21/05/2016 - 27/05/2016
        week 8:28/05/2016 - 03/06/2016

so now my output for week no should be week:6
```

Here i am using java 1.7 so i am not able to use -- import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

How could i achieve, this please help me on this.

Comment: Use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Comment: @Elliott Frisch Joda time is present in Java SE 8,i am working on java SE 7 built project

Comment: @dafodil No, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is a 3rd-party library, not part of Java. I suspect you are thinking of [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) which is built into Java 8 and later, supplants the old date-time classes, and inspired by Joda-Time. The Joda-Time team has advised users to migrate to java.time. Much of java.time functionality is back-ported in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Comment: @Basil Bourque your comment was informative,thanks for that.But i should not use any third party library also as i am working on already bulit project ,it should be maintained by existing libraries and api's .

Comment: @dafodil Are you asking: For a given interval (a pair of date-time values), how many weeks past that interval’s start is a particular date-time value (a third and separate date-time value)?

Comment: @Basil Bourque Please look my updated question i have explained with example.

Comment: @dafodil So that would be a “Yes” to my question? If so I suggest you edit your Question to have a similar short summary of your issue. Also, how *exactly* do you define a week? Is it seven days from whatever start date is submitted? And, what is the point of the second argument, the `End Timestamp`? Seems irrelevant to me, unless you want to check that the "Given Timestamp" is before the "End". Tip: Your example data would be easier to read by the international audience here on Stack Overflow if you stuck with ISO 8601 formats (as does your input data apparently).

Comment: @Basil Bourque .Yes it would be 7 days for a week.End Timestamp is to just check whether given date falls in given date range.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static int getWeekNO(Timestamp startTime, Timestamp endTime, Timestamp dateTime) {
      if (dateTime.compareTo(startTime) < 0 || dateTime.compareTo(endTime) > 0) {
        System.out.println("Not a Valid Date");
        return -1;
      }
      return (int) ((dateTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime() - 1) / (1000L * 3600 * 24 * 7)) + 1;
    }
```

---

**edit:**

As request, updated the answer,

```
public static int getWeekNO(Timestamp startTime, Timestamp endTime, Timestamp dateTime) {
  if (dateTime.compareTo(startTime) < 0 || dateTime.compareTo(endTime) > 0) {
    System.out.println("Not a Valid Date");
    return -1;
  }
  int dayDiff = (int) ((dateTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()) / (1000L * 3600 * 24)) + 1;
  int week = dayDiff / 7;
  return dayDiff % 7 == 0 ? week : week + 1;
}
```

Notice: Be careful about the constructor of Date/Timestamp,

```
  Timestamp startTime = new Timestamp(2016, 5, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  Timestamp dateTime = new Timestamp(2016, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

This constructor the month starts with 0. So the above code is comparing 2016-4-30 to 2016-5-6. It's only one week.

Comment: If you want to ignore "HH:mm:ss", just reset three values of three inputs to zero. It's not included in the answer.

Comment: How to reset "HH:mm:ss" values,Can you show in code ,i searched in google it shows only calender reset.

Comment: if i give startdate as 2016, 05, 17 and dateTime as 2016, 06, 01 it gives 2 week instead of 3 week.How could i correct it

Comment: @dafodil It's edge situation. My calculation is from 2016-05-17 00:00 to 2016-06-01 00:00. The duration is exactly 2 weeks. You can say it's the end of 2 week, or you can say it's the start of 3 week, it's totally ok. It's your decision. Just remove the *-1* from the last line.

Comment: it should not only limit for particular interval,whatever date interval i give it has to work for that.Could you please help me on this

Comment: if startTime = 2016, 04, 25 and dateTime = 2016,05,1,its returning week as 2,But according to calender its week 1 as i am starting from 25th to of april to may 1st,7 days totally. How is this getting changed?

Comment: Oops. I forgot to adjust weeks calculation. I've updated my answer. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: starttime - 2016, 05,30 datetime - 2016,06,6 returns week as 1,instead of week 2.Why i am getting like this?

Comment: @dafodil same result returning week as 1 instead of 2

Comment: same result returning week as 1 instead of 2.for starttime - 2016, 05,30 datetime - 2016,06,6

Comment: @dafodil It returns 2. Please check the *notice* part of the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114520/discussion-between-waltersu-and-dafodil).

Answer (score 0):

## Using java.time

Do not use `java.sql.Timestamp` for business logic. That class is only for exchanging data with your database. And even that purpose is now supplanted by the java.time classes. For Java 7, use the back-port of java.time listed in bullets below.

The troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

### `DayOfWeek`

Specify the day-of-week you consider to be the beginning of a week. Use a`DayOfWeek` enum object.  By the ways, standard [ISO 8601 week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) definition begins with Monday.

```
DayOfWeek dowStart = DayOfWeek.MONDAY ;
```

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

Specify your start/stop dates.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse( 2016 , 4 , 9 ) ; 
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.parse( 2016 , 6 , 28 ) ;
LocalDate first = start.with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( dowStart ) ) ;

List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>() ;
LocalDate ld = first ; // Initialize for loop.
while( ld.isBefore( stop ) ) {  // While the local date is before the stopping point.
    dates.add( ld ) ;
    // Prepare for next loop.
    ld = ld.plusWeeks( 1 ) ;
}
```

Now report on your week-starting dates in any manner you choose.

```
int i = 0 ;  // Initialize for loop.
for( LocalDate ld : dates ) {
    i ++ ;
    String output = "Week # " + i + ":" + ld + " - " + ld.plusDays( 6 ) ;
    …
}
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).